# Sonar Scanner error in Azure DevOps - ERROR : Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sonarqube, sonarscanner, build-pipeline

I’m trying to integrate SonarQube with Azure Devops. I have done the configuration in the SonarQube administrator ( Administration > Configuration > General Settings > ALM Integrations , select the Azure DevOps tab, and click the Create configuration button) and setup the service connection in Azure Devops. Also configured the SonarScanner properties file.

```
sonar.projectkey= Project
sonar.projectName= Project name is given
sonar.login = token from SonarQube
```

Verified the Sonar-scanner using cmd command “sonar-scanner -h”. The sonar-scanner.bat file also has successfully executed.
In Azure devops Build pipeline, have configured the branch - Prepare Analysis Configuration, Run Code Analysis and Publish Quality Gate Result. When we run the pipe it fails with the below error.

```
  ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.



 ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
    
ERROR: Not authorized. Please check the properties sonar.login and sonar.password.

INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

##[error]ERROR:

ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

ERROR:
```

Below are the last lines of the log

```
“GET /batch/file?name=sonar-scanner-engine-shaded-9.0.1.46107-all.jar HTTP/1.1” 200 - “-” “ScannerCLI/4.6.1.2450” “AXtcvnCkoRmL3dzQAADB”



“GET /api/settings/values.protobuf HTTP/1.1” 401 - “-” “ScannerCLI/4.6.1.2450” “AXtcvnCkoRmL3dzQAADC”
```

Kindly help me with the above error. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I made it working.

It turned out that you don't need to put the `sonar.login = token` into the `sonar-project.properties`.

What you need to do is:

- to [generate the token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/) on the Sonar side;
- place it to the service connection properties on Azure DevOps: in your Azure DevOps project, go to **Settings > Service Connections** and pick the service connection you use to connect to Sonar (if you don't have any, probably you should create one. It should be of type `SonarQube`). So in the properties of a service onnection of this type, there is a placeholder for a token, you won't miss it.
- finally, if your service connection is named, say, **SonarConnection**, and you *Sonar project* key is `My-Project`, then your Azure pipeline will be looking like:

```yaml
trigger:
- master
- staging
- dev

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarConnection'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'file'
    projectName: 'My Project'
    projectKey: 'My-Project'
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

(I also use TLS connection to my SonarQube server with Let'sEncrypt certificates.)